# Where to get GHC for centos 6?

Tags: installation, centos, centos-6, haskell, ghc

Can anyone direct me as to how to install GHC? 
I went here: http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/epel-testing-i386/ghc-ghc-6.12.3-6.el6.i686.rpm/download/
and tried both the binary and source packages (though i don't know how to install src.rpm's)

with the binary (.rpm) I got an error when I tried to run it through chrome. The error contained a massive amount of dependencies, the first one being: 
"ghc-ghc-6.12.3-6.el6.i686 requires libHSdirectory-1.0.1.1-ghc6.12.3.so"

a quick "yum search libHSdirectory" returned nothing.

maybe there's a repository I can add for the easiest method of install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)

Comment: it's the most beautiful thing i've ever seen. TONS of results for "yum search ghc" now. Thanks!

Comment: Some steps on how to use this magic would have been nice! :( I found this for anyone who needs it : http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x

Comment: How about ghc-7.8+?

Comment: Grab the SRPM from EPEL7, update it, and rebuild.